# Fill super view using layoutAnchor

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have weird problem, because I can't fill whole area of super view using layout anchor

this is my code from custom UIView class:

```
   private func setupTableView() {
            addSubview(tableView)
            tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            let margins = layoutMarginsGuide

            let trailingAnchor = tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor)
            let leadingAnchor = tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor)
            let topAnchor = tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor)
            let bottomAnchor = tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([trailingAnchor, leadingAnchor, topAnchor, bottomAnchor])
}
```

and in result I get weird margins on the left and right site:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are laying out your `tableView` relative to the margins of the `layoutMarginsGuide`.  If you want it to go to the edges of your `UIView`, then you need to use the anchors of the `UIView`:

```
private func setupTableView() {
    addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let trailingAnchor = tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
    let leadingAnchor = tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor)
    let topAnchor = tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor)
    let bottomAnchor = tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([trailingAnchor, leadingAnchor, topAnchor, bottomAnchor])
}
```

Comment: We've all been there.  Glad I could help.